# CakePHP retrieving data from model using find(). Different array keys on production server

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find, key

I have the same exact code on my production and development servers but I seem to get different array keys when using find('first') to retrieve data.

Development:

```
Array
(
    [Page] => Array
        (
            [title] => Welcome!
            [keywords] => keyword 1 keyword 2 keyword 3
        )

)
```

Production:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Welcome!
            [keywords] => keyword 1 keyword 2 keyword 3
        )

)
```

Code in AppController:

```
//get page title and keywords
        $currentPage = $this->Page->find('first', 
            array(
                'conditions' => array('Page.name' => $this->params['controller']),
                'fields' => array('Page.title', 'Page.keywords')
            ));


        pr($currentPage);
```

Comment: are you sure you're running the same versions of CakePHP?

Comment: Yes I just uploaded the the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this one... :P I had the same problem before

It's caused either by the php version or the mysql version. Check if your server passes the minimum requirements for your cake version

[requirements for cakephp2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html)

[requirements for cakephp1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/908/Requirements)

you can check them using a phpinfo();

Hope this helps

Comment: Server passes the minimum requirements :( Just uploaded a fresh new cakephp and it worked fine. My Production PHP version is 5.2.17 while the Development is 5.3.8 ... I think it's something that has to do with the case sensitivity of the models.. possible?

Comment: dont think so... in my case it was the Mysql version that wasn't correct.. have you checked that too?

Comment: That seems to be different too. My MySQL version is 5 (on both) so that should be okay no? Noticed that lots of other things are not working, including Auth CakePHP 2.0

Comment: hmmm all i cant think of is the Php version... maybe you do need php 5.3, what i would do is to download a version of [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en) with php 5.2.17 and then test the same site with php 5.3 to see if that's the problem

Comment: Problem is with mysql... i uploaded my project on a different server with 5.1 and it worked... php version is 5.2.17 too.. thanks for you help. Auth was solved too because it expects the array to me model keyed and not numeric...

Answer (score -1):

use `$this->set(compact('currentPage',$currentPage));`