# CakePHP2.1 find('all') can't find ModelName in return Array

Tags: cakephp

I did the following query in cakePHP : `$this->{ModelName}->find('all')`  , and it returned an array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array  // ModelName
                (
                    [id] => 83
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
           ...
        )
)
```

Instead of the correct display which is supposed to be like that :

```
Array
(
    [{ModelName}] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array  // ModelName
                (
                    [id] => 83
                    [field1] => value1
                    [field2] => value2
                    [field3] => value3
                )
        )
    [{ModelName}] => Array
        (
           ...
        )
)
```

CakePhp version is 2.1

**A:Don't use PDO_MYSQL-1.0.2.tgz,please use --with-pdo-mysql.**

Comment: Seems duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960500/cakephp-find-not-returning-correctly-missing-model-name

Comment: solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346833/cakephp-retrieving-data-from-model-using-find-different-array-keys-on-product/10348185#10348185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if your server meets the minimums requirements for cakephp ?

> ## Requirements
>
> HTTP Server. For example: Apache. mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required.
>
> PHP 5.2.8 or greater.
>
> Technically a database engine isn’t required, but we imagine that most applications will utilize one. CakePHP supports a variety of database storage engines:
>
> MySQL (4 or greater)
>
> PostgreSQL
>
> Microsoft SQL Server
>
> SQLite
>
> *Note* :
>   The built-in drivers all require PDO. You should make sure you have the correct PDO extensions installed.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#Requirements

You can check your current version within the built-in function in php `phpinfo()`. Just write it in any page. Also check your php.ini file to see if the pdo extension for the database your are using is installed correctly