# cakephp: use find("all") return array in xampp is different from in nginx+mysql

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

My PC web env is xampp and my vps is lnmp:

```
[local web] :

Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4. mysql:5.5.27

[vps]:

Linux / PHP v5.3.3  mysql:5.5.3-m3-log
```

The CakePHP version is latest:2.4.0 Rc2(really,the problem is exists in version:2.2.9);

At first I test Ok in my PC, the code is:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all',array('fields'=>'User.uid,User.username,User.email'));
```

and the result is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["User"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["uid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["username"]=>
      string(9) "zjh_admin"
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "xb_zjh@126.com"
    }
  }         
}
```

When I execute it in my vps, the result is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["uid"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["username"]=>
      string(9) "zjh_admin"
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "xb_zjh@126.com"
    }
  }      
}
```

The first array index is modelname("***User***") ,but the second result array index is ***0***. why?

I'm sure the code is same.
I search the problem long time, I still can't solve it now. Help me! Thanks!

Comment: can you highlight the difference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11960500 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/12003283 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/10346833 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/11960500 | https://google.com/search?q=cakephp+find('all')+missing+model+name

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP find not returning correctly - missing model name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960500/cakephp-find-not-returning-correctly-missing-model-name)

Comment: I try it but it does't solve my problem, I guess my php version or mysql is too high.